# Level Stucked because I haven't any quest to do

Tags: neverwinter

I finished all the quests of **District Tower** and then I did the main quest where I fought with a man who became huge. Now I need to do the quests from BlackDagger Ruins but I can't take any quest from there, neither from Sergeant Knox.

So, What can I do for level up or get new missions?

I am level 20.

Comment: Wow. I've had just the opposite problem. I have quests left behind from nearly every area because I moved on with a different quest line. There are so many different quests and paths, I seem to have tons active at any given time. On my level 51, I have 14 unfinished quests ranging in level from 10 to 51. (3 are below level 20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in any MMORPG, you can get experience from monsters kills. If your level does not allow you to get more quest, just go in an area where the monsters have sufficient level to yield a good amount of experience. Sometimes you can even go to a map where you haven't started any quest.

The wiki has the list of all the quests [here](http://neverwinter.gamepedia.com/List_of_quests). Your next quest starts at level 21.

Comment: +1 Quest List. Wow! That list solve all my doubts. Thank you

Comment: Don't forget about the dailies (dungeon and foundry), too. Those start just after level 10. And invoke, that gives the equivalent of quest-like experience every day, too.

Comment: There are also "contests" in every zone that are similar to quests and sometimes have a "quest" assigned to them for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to gain experience to unlock more quests.

There are three ways to gain experience that don't involve questing:

1. Slay Monsters (go to an area where the monsters are at least your level).
2. Communing with your god (Control - I) near an altar every hour.  There is one located in Protector's Enclave close to Sergeant Knox or you can use a portable altar from your backpack.
3. The leadership crafting skill - most leadership tasks offer some experience.